# Explain why the zero vector in U is a subspace of V.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

1. Let $V$ be an $n$ -dimensional vector space and let $W \subseteq V$ be an $m$ -dimensional subspace. For each $\mathbf{v} \in V$, define $S_{\mathbf{v}}=\{\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w}: \mathbf{w} \in W\}$, and let $U=\left\{S_{\mathbf{v}}: \mathbf{v} \in V\right\}$. Define addition in $U$ so that for any $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in V$
   $$
   S_{\mathbf{x}}+S_{\mathbf{y}}=S_{\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}}
   $$
   and define scalar multiplication so that for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$
   $$
   k S_{\mathbf{x}}=S_{k \mathbf{x}}
   $$
   It can be shown that $U$ is vector space (you do not need to prove this).

Given the above information, I need to explain why the zero vector in $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

This is how I explained it:

Given that $V$ is a n-dimensional vector space and let $W \subseteq V$ is an m-dimensional subspace.

For each $v \in V$, define

$S_{v}=\{v+w: w \in W\}$

$U=\left\{S_{v}: v \in V\right\}$

Define in addition $U$ so that for any $x, y \in V$,

$S_{x}+S_{y}=S_{x+y}$

and define scalar multiplication so that for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$,

$k S_{x}=S_{k x}$

To find zero vector in $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

Every zero vector is a subspace of a vector space.

So,

The trivial space is a subspace of a vector space.

ie, $0 \subseteq U$

Then 0 is also a element of $U$.

$0+0=0$

So, 0 is an element of $V$.

The trivial element is a subspace of a vector space.

Therefore, this explains why the zero vector in U is a subspace of V.

Would this be correct?

Comment: It is important to distinguish the zero vector from the subspace that only contains the zero vector.

Comment: The "vectors" of $U$ are actually sets of vectors of $V$. In fact the zero of $U$ denoted as $0_U$ is $S_0$. Now it is your job to prove how and why $S_0$ is a subspace of $V$. Just use the definitions given to you here.

Comment: It is just weird, if you have shown that $U$ is a vector space, you should have found the zero vector in $U$ and know already that it is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: All good, thank you for the feedback guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid any confusion, I do not use the symbol $0$ for the zero vector in $U$.

Note that every vector in $U$ can be represented as $S_v$ for some vector $v\in V$. In particular, the zero vector in $U$ is $S_z$ with $z\in V$. Let us find $z$.

For any vector $S_x\in U$, by definition of zero, we have:
$$ S_z= 0\,S_x=S_{0\,x}=S_{\vec{0}}$$

Going back to the definition of the sets $S_x$, we have:
$$S_z=S_\vec{0}=\{\vec{0}+w\,:\,w\in W\}=\{w\,:\,w\in W\}=W$$
but $W$ was defined as a subspace of $V$.

Comment: Why $S_{x+z}=S_x\implies x+z=x$?

Comment: $S_x=S_{x+z}$ does not imply that $x=x+z$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I am not sure but anyway it is an unnecessary complication. Edited.

Comment: @ArcticChar Avoided in the edit.